# Locally Overriding the string Extraction Operator

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading, getline, extraction-operator

I have a set of utility functions which read in lines from a stream rather than reading word by word. They work with `string`s, so I'd like to locally change the `string` extraction operator within the scope of these functions only. Is that possible?

---

What I'm doing right now is to create a `struct` that is a `string` and writing an extraction operator for that struct only.

```
struct line{
    string str;
};

istream& operator>>(istream& lhs, line& rhs){
    return getline(lhs, rhs.str);
}
```

And then extracting an `istream` like this:

```
vector<line> foo{ istream_iterator<line>(istringstream("Lorem Ipsum\nLorem Ipsum")), istream_iterator<line>() };
```

This works fine but I do not like the `struct line` wrapper. What I'm asking is, can I locally overload `istream& operator>>(istream& lhs, string& rhs)` to accomplish this instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking for is not possible. There already exists an `istream& >>(istream&, string& )`, so you can't simply overwrite it. Providing another type is already the way to do it.

One thing you could do is provide a conversion from `line` to `std::string` so that your container can just be `std::vector<std::string>` instead of `std::vector<line>`

```
struct line{
    string str;
    operator string() const { return str; }
};

istringstream iss("Lorem Ipsum\nLorem Ipsum");
vector<string> foo{istream_iterator<line>(iss),
                   istream_iterator<line>() };
```

That way the `line` type doesn't have to exist outside of the extraction process and bleed into the rest of your codebase.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, even though it makes me sad. That's actually what I was doing I just didn't want to clutter the question too much.